# Pagination doesn't accept dict as data - unhashable type

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-2.x, django-pagination

I'm trying to use Django pagination [Pagination Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/). But I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError at /
unhashable type
```

Which is basically because I'm using a dictionary as my object and not a queryset.
I would like to know if there is a way to turn my dictionary a hashable object.

This is my dict in template:

```
{% for key, values in prodmatrix.items %}                                                                                                     <li class="span3">
<div class="product-box">
<span class="sale_tag"></span>
<p><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{values.1.0}}" alt="" /></a></p>
    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}" class="title"><h4>{{ values.0.0 }}</h4></a><br/>
    <p class="category"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}">{{values.2.}}    {{values.2.1}}   {{values.2.2}}</a></p>
</div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print "login"
        user = request.user
        prods = Product.objects.all()

        i = 0
        print 'numero de produtos ' + str(len(prods))
        prodmatrix = {}
        for prod in prods:
            #                       0             1           2    3
            prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [], [prod.slug]] 
            reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags
            print str(len(reviews))
            if len(reviews) != 0: 
                for review in reviews:
                    rev_alltags = review.tag.all()
                    for tags in rev_alltags[:3]:     #                           
                        print tags.name
                        prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tags.name) # append only tags 
            print str(i)
            i = i + 1
        paginator = Paginator(prodmatrix, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(paginator.num_page)
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix2':prodmatrix})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tuple` instead `dict`, like this:

```
# convert `dict` to `tuple`:
prodmatrix = tuple(prodmatrix)
paginator = Paginator(prodmatrix, 2)
# or this
paginator = Paginator(prodmatrix.items(), 2)

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    prodmatrix2 = paginator.page(paginator.num_page)
return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix2':prodmatrix})
```

And in you template, you need call the attrs and method by index of tuple (key=0, value=1)

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't get how the code would change in the template. I updated my question with dict code in template. How it would change?

Comment: `items()` is a method of `dict`, but not `tuple`. You already have you data in `tuple` and dont need use `items()` method
{% for key, values in prodmatrix %}
    {{ values.0.0 }}
    {{ values.1.0 }} {{ values.1.1 }} {{ values.1.2 }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Thank you, but the tuple still doesn't work. I tried to parse it  a values.0.0, but it returns '' as a result

Comment: how to check has_previous() in pagination?

Comment: Excellent...saved lot of my time +1