# Django pagination with dictionary where key is a list

Tags: python, django, dictionary, pagination

I have a dictionary in my `views.py` file where the values are lists.  In my template I have the following html:

```
{% for key, values in my_dict %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="key">{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for value in values %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="value">{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

which prints out the name of the key followed by the list items inside the value.  However, I want to be able to paginate the keys such that only 10 keys with their values appear per page.

I have the following code to do the pagination inside my `index` method in `views.py`:

```
paginator = Paginator(myDict, 10)
page_num = requests.GET.get('page', 1)
page = paginator.page(page_num)
```

I updated my template to `{% for key, values in page %}` and of course I get a TypeError because it's a hashable type.  I'm just wondering how I can go about producing the same results as before but without using a dictionary.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870430/pagination-doesnt-accept-dict-as-data-unhashable-type) that suggests using tuples instead of dictionaries, but that doesn't seem to work for me and I'm guessing because my values are lists.

Comment: Do you have the lists as keys or values? You have mentioned both situations (at the beginning and at the end).

Comment: Whoops my bad I'll fix it now. The values are lists and the keys are single objects.  It's a test suite object mapping to its list of test case objects if that's relevant at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be count as good answer but anyway: I have just tried to replicate your problem and solution with `tuple` and it worked. So I think the problem can be in your code. My test code:

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> d = {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}
>>> p = Paginator(d, 1)
>>> p1 = p.page(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type
>>> t = tuple(d.items())
>>> t
(('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [3, 4]))
>>> p = Paginator(t, 1)
>>> p.page(1).object_list
(('a', [1, 2]),)
>>> p.page(2).object_list
(('b', [3, 4]),)
```

UPDATE: and looping also works. So can you show what structures do you have?

Comment: It is definitely my code. I had `tuple(d)` not `tuple(d.items())` and I was also using `t[1]` instead of `t(1)`.  I'll see if I can get it working using your answer and let you know.

Comment: @steveclark `tuple(d)` gives you `('a', 'b')` so just keys.

Comment: Yeah I found that out the hard way haha. Anyways your solution worked.  Also, if anyone finds themselves here in your template you need to use `{% p.page(1).object_list.0 %}` to access the key (.1 for the value). Indexing using `[i]` does not work.

Comment: @steveclark Actually brackets don't work in template too, but I guess you meant `{{ page_object.object_list.0 }}`. Also you can skip `object_list` and just write `{{ page_object.0.0 }}` and `{{ page_object.0.1 }}`.