# Django pagination python dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, pagination

I hope you well.
I’m developing a web using python and Django. I will love to paginate my dictionary `“image_set_list”` in order to see one element in one page, I mean, one element per page.
The problem is that when I get the page, the result is `None` and pagination is not working.

This is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


def detection_detail(request):
 
    # data planogram, bounding_boxes
    with open('detection/data.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
 
    # data image planogram
    image_name_location = data['image']
    image_planogram = os.path.basename(image_name_location)
 
    # data product images
    with open('detection/data_product_images.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data_product_images = json.load(json_file)
    
 
    data_product_image = {x["id"]: x for x in data_product_images}
    
 
    images_reference = []
    list_images = []
 
    for product in data['bounding_boxes']:
        product_id = product['class']
        
        product_ids = product['class_list']
        image_p = data_product_image[product_id]["image_file"]
        image_p_list = [data_product_image[id]["image_file"]
                        for id in product_ids]
        
        images_reference.append(image_p)
        list_images.append(image_p_list)
        
 
    image_set_list = {images_reference: list_images for images_reference,
                      list_images in zip(images_reference, list_images)}
    
    #PAGINATION!!
    paginator = Paginator(image_set_list , 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    print('page', page)
    #result is -> None
    set = paginator.get_page(page)
 
    context = {
        'list_images': list_images, 'images_reference': images_reference,
        'image_planogram': image_planogram, 'image_set_list': image_set_list,
        'image_p_list': image_p_list, 'set': set}
 
    return render(request, "detection/detection_detail.html", context)
```

And this is my detection_detail.html (at the bottom you can see the pagination code.

```html
                <div class="container">

                    {% for image_reference , list in image_set_list.items %}

                    <div class="container">

                        <!--Image Planogramme-->
                        <p> image planogram </p>
                        <a href="{% url 'detection_detail' %}">
                            <img class="img-responsive image-rezise planogram_image"
                                src="/static/images/{{image_planogram}}">
                        </a>
                        <!--End Image Planogramme-->

                        <!--Image Reference-->
                        <a href="{% url 'detection_detail' %}">
                            <p>image detection {{ image_reference }} </p>
                            <img class="img-responsive image-rezise main_image_detection"
                                src="/static/images/{{image_reference}}">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end Image Reference-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        {% for i in list %}

                        <!-- list options Reference-->
                        <p>image option {{ i }}</p>

                        <a href="{% url 'detection_detail' %}">

                            <img class="img-responsive image-rezise set_image_detection" src="/static/images/{{i}}">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end list options Reference-->
                        {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                    {% endfor %}




                </div>

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="pagination">
                            {% if set.has_previous %}
                            <a class="btn btn-primary m2" href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary m-2" href="?page={{ set.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if set.has_next %}
                            <a class="btn btn-primary m-2" href="?page={{ set.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                            <p class="current btn btn-primary m2"> Page {{ set.number }} of
                                {{ set.num_pages }}
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary m-2" href="?page={{ set.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
                            {% endif %}
    
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
            </div>
```

I see nothing related with pagination and I still see all the elements in the same page. I have being checking for a while but not idea what is going on. maybe is because it is a dictionary I can't do this?

I will really appreciate your help gyus! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is printing None because there are no request param with a name of page on your browser URL. It might be probably example.com not this example.com/page=2

```
 ...

 #PAGINATION!!
    paginator = Paginator(image_set_list , 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    print('page', page)
    #result is -> None
    set = paginator.get_page(page)
  
  ...
```

As the structure of the dictionary you are passing is not clear, what I would suggest you do is try Django Shell and run something like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380487/django-pagination-with-dictionary-where-key-is-a-list))

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> d = {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}
>>> p = Paginator(d, 1)
>>> p1 = p.page(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type
>>> t = tuple(d.items())
>>> t
(('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [3, 4]))
>>> p = Paginator(t, 1)
>>> p.page(1).object_list
(('a', [1, 2]),)
>>> p.page(2).object_list
(('b', [3, 4]),)
```

Comment: Great! It worked with tuple, now the URL get the page!. Now my problem is that in my template I'm still seeing the hole items, I mean, it changes the page when I click "next" and "previous", but the template is not showing one element per page! What could be happening ?